# Black screen after installing hardware support

Tags: 12.04, graphics, update-manager, vmware-player

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on my VMware Player. Update Manager popped up this morning with a bunch of updates and I installed them and restarted the OS - I didn't face any problems at all. But I remembered that the Update Manager said "New hardware support is available" on the top, and had a button to install the "hardware support". So I started Update Manager again and saw the same message and button. I clicked on that button and after it installed, I restarted the OS using the "Restart Now" button. Upon restart, the login screen showed up, and after I logged in by entering my password, the screen became completely BLACK. I waited for several minutes, but nothing happened.

After a bit of searching the Internet, I came to know that I can access the terminal from the login screen itself, so I restarted Ubuntu by resetting VMware Player and when the login screen came up, I clicked CTRL + ALT + F1 and a terminal program came up on the screen. I am unsure as to what I should do now. Please help.

By the way, I just remembered - when I clicked on the Install button for the hardware support, I saw a message that said that some graphics thing is no longer going to be maintained starting 8/7/2014 and a new graphics driver or something is the new hardware support.

---

Comment: what is your graphics card?

Comment: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470

Comment: Can you connect to the internet without screeen or in ALT+ Ctrl+F2

Comment: I am accessing the Internet through Windows.

Comment: And yes, I am able to connect to the Internet from the terminal. I pushed some commits to my Github account from the CTRL + ALT + F1 terminal.

Comment: I'm trying it out, just a moment, I'll get back.

Comment: It says "E: Unable to locate xsever-xorg-video-radeon", for both the cases you suggested.

Comment: Sorry. there was a spellings mistake: install the driver package: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon`. If it is already installed, then purge and reinstall: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-video-radeon && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon`. then reboot.

Comment: @user296776 Thank you SO much! It worked! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept your answer! May this help all the others who have a difficult time with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the driver package using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

If it is already installed, then purge and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-video-radeon \
&& sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

You might need to reboot your system for the changes to take effect. (You can reboot from the command line issuing `sudo reboot`.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue after doing the Hardware Update.  If I select "Ubuntu 2D" I can login without getting a black screen.  However, the normal "Ubuntu" login gets a black screen.  It did not update me to 14.04 like Sanapci said, lsb_release -a still shows Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS".

If I wait a while the lock screen displays, but as soon as I enter my password at the lock screen, it goes back to a black screen.

I can get back to the login screen from the black screen by using Cntrl-alt-F1, logging in, and doing a "service lightdm restart".

I have an nVidia graphics card, but this is a VM running VMware unlike the original poster.

I tried downgrading the kernel back to 3.5.0 from 3.13.  I tried reinstalling the VMware tools.  I tried renaming the .config directory.  I tried doing a "unity --reset" while logged into "Ubuntu 2D."

/var/log/syslog fills up with errors like the following when I try to log in:

```
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305188] CPU: 1 PID: 13929 Comm: compiz Tainted: GFO 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305190] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07/31/2013
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305193]  ffff880034c70aa8 ffff88007a657b48 ffffffff81752c9e ffff88007f62fff0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305198]  ffff880034c40a08 ffff88007a657bc8 ffffffffa00b7c72 ffff880034c70aa0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305201]  ffffc9000a16f078 ffff88007a657c20 ffff880034c40000 ffff88007a657ba8
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305204] Call Trace:
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305213]  [<ffffffff81752c9e>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305229]  [<ffffffffa00b7c72>] vmw_cmd_compat_res_check+0x2b2/0x2c0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305236]  [<ffffffffa00b7398>] ? vmw_resource_relocation_add+0x38/0x90 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305243]  [<ffffffffa00b7c9c>] vmw_cmd_res_check+0x1c/0x20 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305249]  [<ffffffffa00b8471>] ? vmw_cmd_set_shader+0x31/0xe0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305255]  [<ffffffffa00b81f0>] vmw_cmd_tex_state+0x90/0xf0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305261]  [<ffffffffa00b78a0>] vmw_cmd_check+0x80/0x130 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305266]  [<ffffffff811dd420>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305273]  [<ffffffffa00b9246>] vmw_execbuf_process+0x216/0x940 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305276]  [<ffffffff811dd420>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305283]  [<ffffffffa00b9a3f>] vmw_execbuf_ioctl+0x7f/0xf0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305296]  [<ffffffffa0003e3a>] drm_ioctl+0x4da/0x600 [drm]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305303]  [<ffffffffa00b99c0>] ? vmw_execbuf_release_pinned_bo+0x50/0x50 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305308]  [<ffffffff811182cc>] ? acct_account_cputime+0x1c/0x20
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305313]  [<ffffffff810a25e9>] ? account_user_time+0x99/0xb0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305320]  [<ffffffffa00bd69e>] vmw_unlocked_ioctl+0x4e/0x70 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305323]  [<ffffffff811dc5c5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x75/0x2c0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305327]  [<ffffffff81022735>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x165/0x280
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305330]  [<ffffffff811dc8a1>] SyS_ioctl+0x91/0xb0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305335]  [<ffffffff8176847f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.305338] [drm:vmw_cmd_check] *ERROR* Invalid SVGA3D command: 1051
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340175] [drm:vmw_cmd_compat_res_check] *ERROR* Could not find or use resource 0x00000000.
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340185] CPU: 1 PID: 13929 Comm: compiz Tainted: GFO 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340187] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07/31/2013
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340190]  ffff880034c70aa8 ffff88007a657b48 ffffffff81752c9e ffff88007f62fff0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340195]  ffff880034c40a08 ffff88007a657bc8 ffffffffa00b7c72 ffff880034c70aa0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340198]  ffffc9000a16f078 ffff88007a657c20 ffff880034c40000 ffff88007a657ba8
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340201] Call Trace:
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340211]  [<ffffffff81752c9e>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340227]  [<ffffffffa00b7c72>] vmw_cmd_compat_res_check+0x2b2/0x2c0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340234]  [<ffffffffa00b7398>] ? vmw_resource_relocation_add+0x38/0x90 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340240]  [<ffffffffa00b7c9c>] vmw_cmd_res_check+0x1c/0x20 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340247]  [<ffffffffa00b8471>] ? vmw_cmd_set_shader+0x31/0xe0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340253]  [<ffffffffa00b81f0>] vmw_cmd_tex_state+0x90/0xf0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340259]  [<ffffffffa00b78a0>] vmw_cmd_check+0x80/0x130 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340264]  [<ffffffff811dd420>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340271]  [<ffffffffa00b9246>] vmw_execbuf_process+0x216/0x940 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340274]  [<ffffffff811dd420>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340281]  [<ffffffffa00b9a3f>] vmw_execbuf_ioctl+0x7f/0xf0 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340294]  [<ffffffffa0003e3a>] drm_ioctl+0x4da/0x600 [drm]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340301]  [<ffffffffa00b99c0>] ? vmw_execbuf_release_pinned_bo+0x50/0x50 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340307]  [<ffffffff811182cc>] ? acct_account_cputime+0x1c/0x20
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340312]  [<ffffffff810a25e9>] ? account_user_time+0x99/0xb0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340320]  [<ffffffffa00bd69e>] vmw_unlocked_ioctl+0x4e/0x70 [vmwgfx]
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340323]  [<ffffffff811dc5c5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x75/0x2c0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340327]  [<ffffffff81022735>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x165/0x280
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340330]  [<ffffffff811dc8a1>] SyS_ioctl+0x91/0xb0
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340336]  [<ffffffff8176847f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
Jul 18 14:54:50 ubu kernel: [  688.340339] [drm:vmw_cmd_check] *ERROR* Invalid SVGA3D command: 1051
```

In my case the fix was doing the following:

apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vmware

Comment: I also had to install: "apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse" after this HWE update otherwise the mouse jumped all over the place when switching between the host and the VM window.

Comment: +1 I just had to switch to `Ubuntu 2D`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because of the hardware update was and upgrade 12.04 to 14.04 which has an error..

I've got this problem too. You should downgrade to 12.04 and it will be working without missing data. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem, running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS inside VMware. "apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vmware" and "apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vmware" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and solved it by:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```