# guest ubuntu ver 12.04 after log in black screen on vmware workstation 10.04

Tags: 12.04

anybody else running into this and has a good fix, google search has work around to uncheck 3d graphics on the display settings on the guest, which works but I lose menubar on the guest desktop.

update driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and solved it by:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

Follow the post:
[Black screen after installing hardware support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499208/black-screen-after-installing-hardware-support)